# How to make classpath work for my app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports

This might be a very dummy question but I really have no idea whats wrong or at least how to solve it...

I am using JasperReports to create a basic report, on the config I need to do this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView report() {

    JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
    view.setUrl("classpath:report2.jrxml");
    view.setApplicationContext(appContext);

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("datasource", carService.getCars());

    return new ModelAndView(view, params);
}
```

based on this [guide](http://zetcode.com/articles/jasperspringbootweb/)

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView: unnamed; URL [classpath:report2.jrxml]] 
does not run in an ApplicationContext
```

and well I do have the jasper file directly under `/resources`

copying the file path is:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\test\src\main\resources\report2.jrxml
```

So, I can be very sure it is there, still no luck implementing, does anybody know how can I do this? What are the alternatives to classpath?

Any idea?